# How to get index value for specific table from mysql?

Tags: mysql, indexing, pagination, cursor

How to get [mysql index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) value for specific table from MySQL?

> "Most MySQL indexes (PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE, INDEX, and FULLTEXT) are
>   stored in B-trees."

As you can check out in documentation it is B-trees?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-index.html

Comment: This is how to find index information. Now question is how to get specific index BTREE object(value). After I get this BTREE I will traverse through it. At the moment I don't know how to get BTREE.

Comment: How do mean traverse through it.?

Comment: It's not important because I need to get BTREE somehow first.

Answer (score 1):

Study BTrees.  More specifically, B+Trees.

Let's search for a single item by the BTree index.  A BTree has a root node; start there.  It has perhaps 100 links to subnodes and information on range of value to be found in each.  You go into the appropriate subnode.  For a small table, you are finished.  But for a huge table, you repeat the process a few times.  (Perhaps 6 iterations for a table with a *trillion* rows.)  Done.  You have found the one row you wanted.

Now, let's fetch a "range" of rows.  (Example:  `WHERE id BETWEEN 1234 and 9876` or `WHERE name LIKE 'T%'`  Do the above to find the first of the range, then go to the 'next' record in the bottom ("leaf") node you are in.  This is fine until you run out of records in the leaf node.

How the `+` in `B+Tree` kicks in.  It means that there is a link from this node to the 'next' node at the bottom level.  So it is quite quick to continue the range query.

Statistics for a million-row table with a "fan-out" of 100:

To find a particular item:  3 nodes (16KB blocks in the case of InnoDB) need to be touched.

To fetch 500 consecutive rows:  3 nodes to get to the start; then about 5 more to scan forward.

Compare...  If there were no index, you would need to scan the entire table of about 10,000 blocks (1M/100).  This would be required for either of the hypothetical queries above.

In InnoDB (in MySQL), nearly all of the keys you ever make will be PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE, and INDEX.  Those are B+Trees; there is no option (unlike other vendors).  Other than that, there are SPATIAL in FULLTEXT; they are more complex.

If you do `SHOW CREATE TABLE foo`, you get some info about the indexes.  `information_schema has further info.

Comment: I have my doubts about the everyday value of knowing that an index is btree or otherwise or how sql traverses the nodes. At the end of the day you tell sql what you want and the optimiser decides how to do what you want,including whether to use an index or not.

Comment: B+Trees are excellent for "point queries" and "range queries".  Still, the Optimizer may _validly_ choose to ignore your index.  Example: Most of the rows are needed anyway; bouncing between the index BTree and the data would be slower than simply scanning all the data.

Comment: This is great information. This is the reason why I somehow need to get B+Trees object. So I can manipulate with it later. Many people probably didn't understand what I need. Thanks @RickJames you got vote up from me.

Comment: @P.Salmon - Yeah, TMI.  Sometimes I feel like giving too much info.  My Comment is the "Executive Summary" -- sufficient for most people.